# change img tag structure for width and height

Tags: php, html, readfile, fwrite

I have an editor in my site that will save images in this format automatically:

```
<img alt="image-alt" src="image-path" style="width: Xpx; height: Ypx;" title="image-title" />
```

this tag will save in static .html file and then will shows in my site with readfile()...
I want to change this structure before saving it in static .html file to this new format:

```
<img alt="image-alt" src="image-path" width="Xpx" height="Ypx" title="image-title" />
```

infact, I want to change the way "width" and "height" is writing in static html file.

I'm using PHP and can run any function on the html string before fwrite() it.

thanks.

Comment: You would need to change the code producing function in the editor, or you could use str_replace() if the output is always the same as above, but I'm guessing the X and Y are just placeholders and the editor is putting in values there? if so, you would probably need to use some regex to get it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I started off thinking this'd be quite easy using preg_replace_callback, but it turned into a bit of a monster. I'm sure it could easily be improved with a bit of refactoring:

```
<?php
// Some HTML test data with two images. For one image I've thrown in some extra styles, just
// to complicate things
$content= '<img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path" style="width: 20px; height: 15px; border: 1px solid red;" title="image-title" />
    <p>Some other tags. These shouldn\'t be changed<br />Etc.</p>
<img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path-2" style="width: 35px; height: 30px;" title="another-image-title" />
<p>This last image only has a width and no height</p>
<img alt="image-alt-3" src="image-path-3" style="width:35px;" title="another-image-title" />';

$content= preg_replace_callback('/<img ((?:[a-z]+="[^"]*"\s*)+)\/>/i', 'replaceWidthHeight', $content);

var_dump($content);

function replaceWidthHeight($matches) {
    // matches[0] will contain all the image attributes, need to split
    // those out so we can loop through them
    $submatches= array();
    $count= preg_match_all('/\s*([a-z]+)="([^"]*)"/i', $matches[1], $submatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $result= '<img ';

    for($ndx=0;$ndx<sizeof($submatches);$ndx++) {
        if ($submatches[$ndx][1]=='style') {
            // Found the style tag ...
            $width= ''; // Temporary storage for width and height if we find them
            $height= '';

            $result.= ' style="';
            $styles= split(';', $submatches[$ndx][2]);
            foreach($styles as $style) {
                $style= trim($style); // remove unwanted spaces

                if (strlen($style)>6 && substr($style, 0, 6)=='width:') {
                    $width= trim(substr($style, 6));
                }
                elseif (strlen($style)>7 && substr($style, 0, 7)=='height:') {
                    $height= trim(substr($style, 7));
                }
                else { // Some other style - pass it through
                    $result.= $style;
                }
            }
            $result.= '"';
            if (!empty($width)) $result.= " width=\"$width\"";
            if (!empty($height)) $result.= " height=\"$height\"";
        }
        else {
            // Something else, just pass it through
            $result.= $submatches[$ndx][0];
        }
    }

    return $result.'/>';
}
```